# What's to do with images that don't help with the question

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

Some people attach images in their questions, even if these don't add any value in helping others to answer the question ([example](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/1428/)). Should these be edited?

Comment: related http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/q/1840

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I agree with Tylershads, if it’s nothing but hindering the question, remove it.  However, in this particular instance I think it serves as a reminder of what The Joker’s makeup looked like, so it’s an ok image to have with the question.  If it had just been a random picture from the movie that didn’t include the Joker then I could see removing or replacing it.

Comment: I agree too, like all edits of a question or answer you should respect the previous person's contribution and only remove if it is hindering the question.

Answer (score 3):

In general, I don't see a reason to edit the images out.

However, if they are completely **off-topic** pictures, for example, a picture of *My Little Pony* on a *Matrix* question, by all means edit out as it clearly does not belong.  Also, if the question is rampant with pictures (read: 7 where only 1 is really needed) then again, feel free.  But there is nothing wrong with a little visual aid of a scene, character and the such.

Comment: I am referring to cases where the image doesn't help at all, as in the attached example. That is, they don't serve as a visual aid.

Comment: Can you explain specifically why it hurts the question?  I honestly don't see much of a problem.

Comment: One way to look at it is *what value does it add?*. Anyways, my response above had more to do with your justification... *visual aid*.